# Set Cell Not Creating Tiles in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a script in GDScript that contains a simple mouse position listener, and a `set_cell` function that sets a cell. For some reason, when I set the cell on my simulation, it doesn't spawn. The mouse position is set correctly, and the set cell position, when set to `(1, 1)`, works. But for some reason. This does not. Here is my code:

```
func _process(delta):
    var mouse_pos = get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
    var mx = mouse_pos.x
    var my = mouse_pos.y
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("click"):
        set_cell(mouse_pos.x, mouse_pos.y, 0)
```

If you find a mistake, feel free to tell me, otherwise, have a nice day, and I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to bet it is creating them out of view.

---

First of all, you are getting the mouse position relative to the `Viewport`:

```
var mouse_pos := get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
```

And second `set_cell` wants map coordinates. We can convert local coordinates to map coordinates with `world_to_map`. But first we need to get the mouse position in local coordinates.

We can try getting it out of `get_viewport().get_mouse_position()`, which I believe would be like this:

```
var mouse_pos := make_canvas_position_local(get_viewport().get_mouse_position())
```

Or better yet, take the mouse position in local coordinates already:

```
var mouse_pos := get_local_mouse_position()
```

Once we have the local mouse position, we can convert local coordinates to map coordinates:

```
world_to_map(mouse_pos)
```

And since that is a vector, let us use `set_cellv`:

```
var mouse_pos := get_local_mouse_position()
# …
set_cellv(world_to_map(mouse_pos), 0)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks!